# How to find encrypted strings in an executable?

Tags: windows, encryption, windbg, encodings, strings

I am trying to reverse engineer an executable.

I am using **Process explorer** to dump all strings present in the exe image, and from the process's RAM when it is running.

[image: process explorer string dump]

The two dumps return a different number of strings, with the latter (from RAM) returning a much greater number of them.
This discrepancy could mean one of the following.

1. **Executable is encrypted (a packer is used?)**
2. **Executable is compressed**
3. **Strings are encrypted/obfuscated**
4. **Strings are coming from a DLL loaded by the process, or a file opened by it.**

I used various tools to rule out 1, and 2. These tools check file entropy and do other statistical checks to figure this out.

Some of the tools I used:

1. Check which packer is being used: https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/PEiD
2. Statistical analysis for enccryption/compression - `binwalk -EJ <exe-name>`, https://github.com/kiathan/Encryption-Detector

To rule out 4 I used process explorer to check each open file handle and loaded DLL. Found nothing suspicious.

**For 3, I proceeded as follows.**

I attached process to WinDbg, and tried to search for a string from RAM string dump obtained from process explorer.

eg. searching for string "--control".

`s -a 0 L?80000000 "--control"`

This string was present at location `014ebbf5`.
To figure out what kind of memory this address is present in, I used WinDbg's `!address` command.

Here is the output I got.

```
Usage:                  Image
Base Address:           01165000
End Address:            01560000
Region Size:            003fb000 (   3.980 MB)
State:                  00001000          MEM_COMMIT
Protect:                00000002          PAGE_READONLY
Type:                   01000000          MEM_IMAGE
Allocation Base:        00c70000
Allocation Protect:     00000080          PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY
Image Path:             C:\Program Files (x86)\<exe-path>.exe
Module Name:            <exe-name>
Loaded Image Name:      C:\Program Files (x86)\<exe-path>.exe
Mapped Image Name:      
More info:              lmv m <exe-name>
More info:              !lmi <exe-name>
More info:              ln 0x14ecbf5
More info:              !dh 0xc70000


Content source: 1 (target), length: 7340b
```

I was expecting this to be an address from `stack` or from `heap`, but it is instead from the process's `READ ONLY` area where memory-mapped file of the executable is present. A read only area cannot store decoded string since you would have to read encoded strings, decode it, and then write them somewhere.

At this point I feel that neither the exe is encrypted, nor compressed, and neither the strings are encoded/encrypted. Still, somehow a lot of strings are not present in the exe, but present in the RAM.
How can this be possible?

Comment: Run strings.exe anydesk.exe > foo.txt to find the visible strings belonging to a executable  or find the module basevand size and provide that as range not 0 to 80000000

Comment: @blabb I have already tried that, and that is the point of contention. strings command doesn't give me enough strings.

Comment: If you have a string you have an address if you have an address you have a raw byte which is either transformed or a clean slate where it is wriiten to so you alwAys have the option of breaking on read access , write access, memory access , use hardware breakpoints and look and your assumptions that read onlyarea  cant a be written is  not correct you can use virtual protect to even execute from there

Comment: It turns out that strings are constructed on the fly. At that time the memory is PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE. Later the permission is changed to read-only.

Answer (score 1):

During my analysis I use [Floss](https://github.com/fireeye/flare-floss)!, it is an excellent tool and super simple to use, on several occasions I can find the strings I am looking for, you used PEID to check for packers please use a more up-to-date tool like DIE (Detect it Easy), if it is an .EXE file consider analyzing with a professional and updated debbuger like x96DBG(x64dbg/x32dbg), I believe you get better results that way.

Comment: I had used Floss earlier without success, and also DIE. Thanks a lot for suggesting x64dbg/x32dbg. They are amazing.